# drop dataframe rows with a for loop

Tags: python, dataframe, drop

Suppose I have a list with wrong users

```
wrong_users = [1,5,8,9,10]
```

I want to use this list to drop those users from the data drame df_users containing a column with all the users

I tried using a for loop:

```
for x in wrong_users:
    if x == df_users['user']:
        df_users.drop([x])
```

but I get the following error: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a loop for that, try this.

```
wrong_users =  [1,5,8,9,10]

df_users = df_users[~df_users['users'].isin(wrong_users)].reindex()
```

Comment: Thank you it worked, but I was wondering where the '~' used for?

Comment: The tilde (~) is bitwise a complement operator, it's being used here to flip the values returned by df_users['users'.isin(wrong_users) from True to False and vice versa.